# Python: Identifying whether all characters of a word are present in a single string

Tags: python, string

I am a python user. I want to check whether a particular word contains characters from a string.

For example i have a word "mizaner". All its characters are present in the string "randomnizer".

I can identify whether a particular substring is part of a string eg. i can verify if "random" is part of "randomnizer" by using the **if** 'random' **in** 'randomnizer': statement but I cannot do the same for "mizaner" as even though all its characters are found in "randomnizer", the characters are jumbled up and the word cannot be used as a substring. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the intended response to `'mizzzaner' in 'randomnizer'` - all of the characters are in `randomnizer` just not the quantity?

Answer (score 8):

The Boolean expression

```
set('mizaner') <= set('randomnizer')
```

will return `True` since all the letters of the first string are in the second string. A similar expression will return `False` if there are any letters in the first string that are not in the second string.

This works because converting a string to a set removes duplicate characters and makes the order of the characters not matter, which is just what you want. The less-than-or-equal-to comparison for sets tests for the subset relation.

Comment: Using `<` instead of `<=` doesn't seem to be what's intended by the problem statement.

Comment: @DSM: Oops, you are correct, of course. Thanks for the notice. I have corrected my error.

Answer (score 1):

To handle cases where character counts matter, not just presence of characters, you'd want:

```
from collections import Counter

word = "randomnizer"
searchlets = "mizaner"
if not (Counter(searchlets) - Counter(word)):
    # All the letters in searchlets appeared in word
```

If count doesn't matter, as others have noted:

```
if set(searchlets).issubset(word):
```

will do the trick. Using `issubset` instead of `set(searchlets) <= set(word)` is slightly better theoretically, since the implementation could choose to avoid converting `word` to a `set` at all and simply stream it by with short-circuiting if the subset condition becomes impossible midway through. In practice, it [looks like CPython internally converts non-`set` arguments to `set` anyway](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/setobject.c#l1714), so unless the implementation changes, both approaches are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
set(word).issubset(string)
```

..

```
word="mizaner"
string="randomnizer"
if set(word).issubset(string):
    print("All characters in word is in string")
```